# Saving files and listing them in default directory

Tags: c#, file, directory

When I want to save a file I use:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName + ".asdf", FileMode.OpenOrCreateOrReadOrBlah);
```

which will save the file in:
C:\Users\ME\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Project A\Project A\Project A\bin\x86\Debug
which is fine

but how do i list the files in that particular folder?
it will be different for every computer

```
List<string> fileNames = new List<string>();

DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(****What goes here?****);
FileInfo[] rgFiles = di.GetFiles("*.asdf");
foreach (FileInfo fi in rgFiles)
   {
      fileNames.Add(fi.Name);
   }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to specify the directory to save to e.g. `FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"c:\file.txt", FileMode.Open);` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your save, you are not specifying a directory, so it defaults to the current directory.

```
var di = new DirectoryInfo(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
```

Comment: I see.  So the compiled exe just happens to be in C:\Users\ME\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Project A\Project A\Project A\bin\x86\Debug so that's why it saves there.

Answer (score 1):

First off, when you save a file without a path, it goes into the current working directory, not necessarily Debug.

Secondly, you can get the current working directory with:

string currentPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory;

Answer (score 0):

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(****What goes here?****);
```

"Here" is where the directory name which you want to manipulate would go.